Scaling (Integer and non-Integer) and Letter/Pillar Boxing
I want to view various types of content on a single display without constantly switching between different screens, while also avoiding any possible artifacts. Specifically, I'm interested in understanding the difference between a single pixel in a 720p resolution and a corresponding 36-pixel block in an 8K resolution when using integer scaling.
How does scaling cause aliasing (if aliasing is the only problem when scaling) and/or introduce image artifacts, can't the computer letter/pillar box if ever needed; i.e why can't a 36" 1440p screen (using only 56.25% of its pixels) display the same thing as a 27" 1080p screen if non-integer scaling and interpolation is a problem?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@JoepvanSteen The issue is whether there are distortions (or even if they are possible) or not. I also view video that is lower resolution than my monitor. Some people claim it would look best in a monitor that matches the resolution of the video. How does upscaling distort the image or create artifacts? Isn't it easy to paint X pixels the same color in the place of 1? Isn't easy to letter/pillar box when X isn't a square of a natural number (just use the closest square and paint black the rest of the screen)?

@JoepvanSteen I don't know them personally. I have seen comments in reddit etc. Should I find some and quote them? I have asked some of them and they either didn't reply or told me that is how it looks to them and aren't interested in information based on or calculated through theory rather than experience or practice.

George, your question has been answered. Please mark the answer as such.

@music2myear It hasn't I didn't ask anything abour the OSD. The question asked for an explanation How does scaling cause aliasing and/or introduce image artifacts? it was not about someone doing something (like adjusting the OSD).

If you think the answer was about OSDs or someone "doing something" then you've misread it and I made a mistake rescinding my vote to close this question.

@music2myear Many displays are capable of this. In the diaply's OSD menu, select 1:1 pixel scaling, no scaling, or similar setting.
If the display's OSD doesn't have this setting, you may be able to force pillar and/or letter-boxing or integer scaling in the display settings: The answer tells me to select and that I can force adjusting the OSD settings. The question was not about how to force letter or pillar boxing.

@JoepvanSteen They were vague "It looks worse in a 4k screen" "A 1080p video looks best on a 1080p screen" but we have moved from this (that it looks worse) now the question (the wording) is How does scaling cause aliasing and/or introduce image artifacts? It was reopened because I improved the question. Let's move on, don't get stuck on previous versions of the question. The question improved.

@JoepvanSteen Both. One can't improve a question that is Too Subjective to answer with Evidence unless they ask a slightly different thing. It moved from The Subjective Looking Worse to the Objective Causing Image Artifacts, Distortions and Aliasing.

@JoepvanSteen Would you rather have the question starting with the Interrogative Does instead of How? Does scaling cause...? Move on from what some people on Reddit said.

@JoepvanSteen I moved goalposts once (not again as you said). When I needed to reopen it (it had no answers and I needed to improve it). Please explain what is the problem with the question as it is now. How does scaling cause aliasing and/or introduce image artifacts? How is it subjective (opinion based), too broad, off-topic etc?


why can't a 36" 1440p screen (using only 56.25% of its pixels display the same thing as a 27" 1080p screen

Many displays are capable of this. In the diaply's OSD menu, select 1:1 pixel scaling, no scaling, or similar setting.
If the display's OSD doesn't have this setting, you may be able to force pillar and/or letter-boxing or integer scaling in the display settings: 
Integer scaling doesn't really cause aliasing, but integer scaling may make aliasing more obvious by reducing the effective pixels per inch and increasing the effective pixel size.
CRT displays use a rapidly moving electron beam to excite phosphor to draw images on the display. This approach takes advantage of persistence of vision to display what looks like an image across the full display, even though only a small fraction of the display is actually illuminated. Because of this approach, a CRT display may appear less pixelated and show less aliasing, but have many other drawbacks. As a result, an image designed to be displayed on a CRT may show more pixelation and aliasing when viewed on a modern display.

But "there was" no previous higher resolution. The previous resolution was lower (that is why it needed upscaling). We have two screens with the same screen size (if the resolutions are integer multiples) or two screens that the "usable" surface is equal (e.g a 36" 1440p and a a 27" 1080p). We need to display a 1080p video (that is what it was, it wasn't downscaled) on a 1440p screen. Why do I need to mess with OSD settings? I want to know why can't I expect my 8k (or 4k to be realistic) 32" screen to be able to display content of any resolution at least as well as any lower resolution screen.

I don't understand what you're reaching for with your comment. It seems like you're asking "why don't display manufactuers use a diffierent scaling behavior by default?" which is probably off-topic for Super User. Your assertion that a 8K/4K screen is unable to dispay a lower resolution is incorrect and the steps in my answer will display lower resolution content on the display without any scaling artifacts. You may need to change settings in the OSD because displays typically use scaling for input resolutions lower than their native.

No I am definately not asking a question about manufacturers' behavior or policy. I am now not longer sure there was a term (much less that it was integer scalling specifically). I am the 8k display controller/software the simplest thing for me to do when I am fed a 720p image (921600 colours to draw pixels with) is to draw 33177600 pixels instead (just draw a 36 pixel block in the place of each pixel). I didn't even know what "scaling" was (now I think what I meant and what mokubai said may be different). I also did not assert that a 8k screen is unable to display a lower resolution.

The last part of your comment captures a bit of my question. The question is why would I need to do anything? Why would there be artifacts or distortions without adjusting the OSD?

The panel inside of a monitor can only display one resolution. Displays contain a scaler as part of the display engine to support a range of input resolutions, otherwise a non-conforming input would only show an error. Display manufacturers generally implement non-linear scaling to support by default, which accommodates the widest range of input resolutions. You would need to poll every display manufacturer to gain a complete answer as to why, but the broad strokes are that it's the simplest (and therefore least expensive) and best aligns to consumer expectations.

The question has nothing to do with manufacturers' behavior or policy (or why the choose it). What they do is given (merely data). What I want with the question is to understand how do I get aliasing, artifacts, distortions with lower content resolutions that the screen resolution.

@Amorphous The issue is whether there are distortions (or even if they are possible) or not. I also view video that is lower resolution than my monitor. Some people claim it would look best in a monitor that matches the resolution of the video. How does upscaling distort the image or create artifacts? Isn't it easy to paint X pixels the same color in the place of 1? Isn't easy to letter/pillar box when X isn't a square of a natural number (just use the closest square and paint black the rest of the screen)?

You should write a new question that's clear on what you're looking for an answer on. My answer to your question provides steps to eliminate scaling artifacts, enable appropriate letter/pillar boxing and some information on the nature of artifacts (compared to CRTs). Super User isn't a discussion forum, it's a knowledgebase. Extended discussion to reframe your question in the comments section, or answer additional questions, is inappropriate.

@Amorphous I did not ask for steps to eliminate scaling artifacts. The question about the nature of artifacts (if that is how you interpret how does upscaling cause artifacts). I was to understand the mechanism. The discussion is not to reframe the question (I asked so I am only explaining what I asked). The comments were to ask for clarification on the answer.

@Amorphous To illustrate how I explain (not reframe) the question, or try to ask for clarifications. You came up with "previous higher resolution" but at no point (in no previous version of the question) was a previous higher resolution mentioned or even implied.

I think you misunderstood the sentence; I removed those few words to hopefully provide more clarity.

Taking from your question, my answer directly addresses these fragments from your question: 1) "view various types of content on a single display without constantly switching between different screens, while also avoiding any possible artifacts" 2) "can't the computer letter/pillar box if ever needed" 3) "How does [integer] scaling cause aliasing?" If you're trying to find out something else, it's really not that clear from your question.

@Amorphous The question asked for an explanation How does upscaling cause aliasing and/or introduce image artifacts? it was not about someone doing something (like adjusting the OSD). There was no fragment of a question in "can't the computer letter/pillar box if ever needed" it was a rhetorical device. I wasn't asking how to make my screen do it (I think it would be obvious it will or at least can do it automatically). I was arguing/asking Since the screen can use integer scalling and letter/pillar box why is upscalling a problem (cause image artifacts or aliasing)?

@Amorphous The question asked for an explanation How does scaling cause aliasing and/or introduce image artifacts? it was not about someone doing something (like adjusting the OSD). There was no fragment of a question in "can't the computer letter/pillar box if ever needed" it was a rhetorical device. I wasn't asking how to make my screen do it (I think it would be obvious it will or at least can do it automatically). I was arguing/asking: Since the screen can use integer scaling and letter/pillar box why is upscaling a problem (cause image artifacts or aliasing)?

@Amorphous The second version of the comment was to fix the mistaken use of up (since it is integer scaling not integer upscaling). I missed the part of the question that answered "How does [integer] scaling cause aliasing?". I was also asking about other image artifacts and distortions caused by scalling (not just aliasing). The first part was no fragment of question it was my motivation (the reason I asked). The only question is the third "fragment" but includes artifacts and distortions caused by scaling (Why/how would scaling cause them).

You may have intended that as a "rhetorical device" but it is a question in a place where questions are asked, and you did not clearly indicate that this "question" was not one. Also, it appears you've posted the same comment twice.

@music2myear The question was How does scaling cause aliasing (if aliasing is the only problem when scaling) and/or introduce image artifacts, the question ended with the comma.  I see no explanation of how does scaling cause aliasing, artifacts or distortions.  can't the computer letter/pillar box if ever needed; i.e why can't a 36" 1440p screen (using only 56.25% of its pixels) display the same thing as a 27" 1080p screen if non-integer scaling and interpolation is a problem? it was at least clear that I wasn't asking how to force letter/pillar box or 1:1  pixel scaling.

Suggest re-writing your question or making a new question. Your current question isn't clear, which is why you're not getting responses you find useful or informative. Suggest removing specifics and ask the general questions you're looking answers for. I.e. "How does scaling cause artifacts?" "Why don't products show unscaled input by default?" Etc.
